# What is the difference between Control source and Bound Source in Combo/List Box?

Tags: ms-access, vba

In the Property Sheet for Combo / List Box,  we have Control Source and we also have the bound column.

How is control Source different from bound column?

Answer (score 1):

The `Control Source` is the field in a table your combo box is linked to, it could also be a query or an SQL statement.  Either way it will display the data in that field and any updates you make to the combo box will be reflected in that field (unless it's a non-update-able query).
https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/ControlSource-Property-994c3208-c4e5-431d-8ec8-dabd5f91c77e

The `Bound Column` is linked to the `Row Source`.  The Row Source tells the combo box what data is supplied to the combo box.  Generally this will be the primary key of a list and a description of the items in that list, for example PersonID and PersonName.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Access-VBA/articles/combobox-rowsource-property-access

The `Bound Column` tells the combo box which field of data in the `Row Source` to store in the `Control Source` field.  So when you select PersonName the PersonID for that record will be stored.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Access-VBA/articles/combobox-boundcolumn-property-access

### Example

I have set up two tables in my database:
[image]
`tbl_List` contains four records used to populate our combo-box.

`Main_Field_A` in `tbl_Main` will hold the bound column value selected in the combo-box (this will be the Foreign Key linked to tbl_Lists Primary Key).
The `Property Sheet` for the combo-box is set up as below:
[image]
Note the `Row Source Type` is `Table/Query`.
We could type `SELECT Field_A, Field_B FROM tbl_List;` into the `Row Source` for the same result.
We could also manually enter the items in the list by typing `1;Item1;2;Item2;3;Item3;4;Item4` and changing the `Row Source Type` to `Value List`

In addition the `Format` tab has the `Column Count` set to 2 and the `Column Widths` set to `1cm;1cm`.  Usually the first, or bound column will have it's width set to 0cm so it is hidden.
[image]

In the below example I've changed the column widths to `0cm;1cm` so the bound column is hidden.
[image]
As you can see it's entered the Primary Key value into the table, rather than the description.

The query to return the record would be:

```
SELECT    Main_Field_ID
        , Field_B
        , Main_Field_B
FROM    tbl_Main INNER JOIN tbl_List ON tbl_Main.Main_Field_ID = tbl_List.Field_A
```

or you could use the `Lookup Field` functionality in Access, but that leads to the darkside.
http://access.mvps.org/access/lookupfields.htm

Comment: Hi Darren,  Thanks for your instant response...  I could understand it from a theoretical point.  It did give me some clarity now. Still I have a little doubt to implement this  in VB code.  I shall be grateful if you could illustrate with an example with a few lines of code...   Thanks again so much for taking the effort to draft the reply...

Comment: My understanding - reading your paragraphs..
<Bound Column> is a kind of a Key-Value Pair…  “Key” (primary Key) ,  “Value” (Description) …   While the Value (Description) is selected by the user… the corresponding “Key” (Primary Key)  is captured into the cmboBox’s Variable…
This cmboBox’s Variable gets assigned to the “Field” mentioned in the <Control Source>,  
At a high level,  <Control source> is attributed to the TABLE, whereas the <Bound column> is attributed to the Combo box (transient Receptacle). 
Bottom Line 
RowSource ComboBox [ boundColumn]ControlSource [tableField]

Comment: I've added an example.  Basically what you said in your comment.

Comment: Hi Darren,  Thanks so much....  it solved my problem..  Grateful that you took so much time off and put efforts to give complete details